# Write to a stream as if it were a file, but really write to an object

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

I am trying write a stream to the ram instead of a file. I tried doing this:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
stream.Close();
return stream;
```

But when I look at the stream after I have supposedly written to it it is saying "Length = 'stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `stream.Close()`, which is exactly the same as calling `Dispose()` on the stream.

Just remove that line of code, and you should be fine.  Basically, you need to leave the `MemoryStream` open when it's returned.

On a different note, depending on what you're going to do, you may also want to reset the stream's position.  I suspect you'll want:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
stream.Position = 0;
return stream;
```

This works the same as your code, but does not `Dispose()` the stream (since it's no longer calling `stream.Close()`), and also resets it to the start position, which is often required if you want to read the object/data back out.

Answer (score 5):

Don't close the stream before getting the data, and don't return the stream but the content of the stream:

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
  BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
  return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call stream.Close (or IDisposable.Dispose()) until you're done with the stream.

You probably need to set the stream position back to start `stream.Position = 0;`

Make sure that you do dispose of the stream when you're done.  The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you `stream.Close();` the object.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you call `Close()`. From [MSDN: Stream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)

> Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets
>   and file handles) associated with the current stream.

You should be able to simply remove `stream.Close();`.